# fullCalendar scheduler grouped events in free spaces

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have 4 events, Z and Z1 in the same group and C and C1 in other group.

I have two resources, Line 1 and Line 2. When I move any event, the grouped event also moves with it, which works perfect. The problem I have is when it overlaps, the shortest event fill an empty space:

Overlapped events:

[image]

I would would like to keep grouped event together, similar to this picture but in the same resource:

Correct structure:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent shorter event to fill these free spaces and keep both grouped event structure?

Comment: You'd have to rewrite the rendering engine for the timeline view, and create your own custom view.

Comment: you mean to modify js library or is there any method to do it better? thanks for answering.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js for further details of what I'm talking about. Basically you would have to copy the code of the existing timeline view and then modify it to make it do what you want. As that documentation explains, it's not necessarily a simple or short task.

Comment: this way is to modify simple event view, but i don't think for grouped events could be done. I think what i need is not the same. I need to prevent grouped events to being separated when events overlaps. I need the second picture structure in the same resource. I need like a position block for grouped events.

Comment: " i don't think for grouped events could be done". With a custom view you are re-creating all the code for the view, including all the code which positions the events in the correct place. That is true for all types of events, whether they are grouped or not. That documentation, as it says itself, only shows you the very basics of what is possible - you have to study the source code of FullCalendar to understand the rest of it. The only way you are going to achieve the functionality you want is by re-writing the view code. There is no way to do it by changing the settings or whatever.

Comment: okey, thanks i will check so. Thanks for helping.